# Detecting new data in a replicated MongoDB slave

Tags: mongodb, replication, database

**Background:** I have a very specific use case where I have an existing MongoDB that I need to interact with  via reads, but I have to ensure that the data can never be modified.  However I also need to trigger some form of event when new data comes in so I can do post processing on it.

The current plan is to use replication to get the data onto a slave for the read processing.  However for my purposes I only care about new data in various document stores.  Part of the issue is that I can not modify the existing MongoDB and not all the data is timestamped, so there is no incremental way to handle this that I can think of.

**Question:** Is it possible to fire an event from a slave that would tell me I have new data and what it is?  I will only have access to the slave DB, as the master will be locked.

I *may* have some limited ability to change the master DB, but I can not expect to change the document structure at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a master/slave configuration you could instead use a replica set with a [priority 0 secondary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-secondary-only-replica-set-member/) (so that it can never become primary).

You can [tail](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/#create-tailable-cursor) the [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#oplog) on that secondary looking for insert operations.